# avoid transient .TransientPropertyValueException without using cascade=Cascade.ALL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'd like to resolvea Transient Object Exception without adding **Cascade=CascadeType.ALL**. At the beginning, so here are my entities. The first one is **Person.java**

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@ManyToOne
//(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
---------
}
```

**Address** have just two elements in data base ("label"= USA, "label" =Canada). It's a data repository. Until here every thing is alright, but the problem begins here with these two entities.

This is my entity **Contract**:

```
public class Contract implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

private int id;

@ManyToOne(cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
private Person person;
}
```

The last and the most important entity **Company.java**:

```
public class Company implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Contract contract;
    }
```

And here is the problem, when I want to create a company I got this error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

Some of you would tell me add **Cascade=CascadeType.ALL** before private Address address but I do not want to do that because address is a data repository and I do not want to persist it I can do cascade of all things execpt persist.

Thank you for yout help.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Address` objects are effectively static data in the database then you must first look them up and then assign them to their respective `Person` objects. You cannot just populate them with data and assign them.

```
  Address usaAddress = em.createTypedQuery("select a from Address where label = 'USA'", Address.class)
                         .getSingleResult();

  Person usaPerson = new Person();
  usaPerson.setAddress(usaAddress);
  ...
```

JPA will know that it does not need to persist the `usaAddress` again unless you do something to change it's state.

Answer (score 0):

The solution were easy I had just added **@Transient** annotation